# preventing SQL Injection using regular expression

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-injection

I know it is so wrong to defend SQL Injection this way (regular expression) and i must use parametrized queries but this time i have an special situation. I'm writing a form generator program and i have to write a complicated search user control so this time there is no other way for me (I think)!

Any way i am looking for a regular expression to check input strings (server side) whether there is any attack like queries on it or not.

Comment: Why can't you use parameters? Just name them `@P0`, `@P1` etc.

Comment: You _can_ build parameterized searches entirely out of content provided by trusted users and then feed the query data from your untrusted users. I even expect designing your program with this in mind will lead to much cleaner code than one that tries to paper over problems with regular expressions.

Comment: My advice: don't spend any time on this. Spend time on figuring out how to use parameters instead.....

Comment: Securing it with regular expressions might even end you up with being vulnerable to regular expression DoS attacks: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Answer (score 1):

I would also say to do this the correct way using a parameterised stored procedure. The basic idea is you set all the parameters to null and then only pass the ones you want to search on. Your WHERE clause then looks like this

```
WHERE (MyColumn1=@Param1 OR @Pram1 IS NULL)
AND (MyColumn2=@Param2 OR @Pram2 IS NULL)
```

Here are some more details

http://weblogs.asp.net/rmclaws/archive/2004/02/18/75381.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard because the regular expression can use two approaches:

1. Accept valid SQL only
2. Reject invalid SQL

Both are hard. My guess is that #1 is safer because you reject all except valid SQL but it will be quite hard to prevent invalid SQL in the valid SQL without restricting the the possibilities too much.

In the end you'll find that using parameters is much safer because as long as you do not execute the passed strings there is no danger of SQL injection.